# Understanding the covariance definition

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, covariance

I just need a small clarification on the covariance definition of my textbook.

The definition is given to me as:

[image]

Am I correct to assume that in here

$\mu_1=E(Y_1)=\int \limits^\infty_{-\infty}y_1f1(y_1)dy_1$

$\mu_1=E(Y_1)=\int \limits^\infty_{-\infty}y_2f_2(y_2)dy_2$

Where:

$f_1(y_1)=\int \limits^\infty_{-\infty}f(y_1,y_2)d y_2$

$f_2(y_2)=\int \limits^\infty_{-\infty}f(y_1,y_2)d y_1$

?

Comment: Yes, that will be so if they  are *continuous real-valued* random variables with the given joint and marginal probability density functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compute $\mu_1$ as 
$$\mu_1 = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}y_1 f(y_1,y_2)dy_2 dy_1$$
which is also
$$\mu_1 = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}  y_1 \Big( \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(y_1,y_2)dy_2 \Big) dy_1$$
If you call $f_1(y_1) =\int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(y_1,y_2)dy_2 $, then 
$$\mu_1 = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}  y_1 f_1(y_1) dy_1$$. So what you mention is correct. Similarly, you apply the same for $\mu_2$